# Elements indexed correctly but not showing in search

Tags: search

I successfully indexed around 600 documents but they do not show when I  searching am

PS: I have to webapp one for https and another for http and I deleted the sps3 one, I am using https in the content source.

Should I add the http version and the sps3 back ?

Answer (score 0):

The SPS3 protocol is used for crawling people profiles, so should add it again.

For the content search, I suggest you to follow the [best practices](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn535606.aspx) and use the default zone url in the content source:

> **Crawl the default zone of SharePoint web applications**
>
> When you crawl the default zone of a SharePoint web application, the
>   query processor automatically maps and returns search-result URLs so
>   that they are relative to the alternate access mapping (AAM) zone from
>   which queries are performed. This makes it possible for users to
>   readily view and open search results. However, if you crawl a zone of
>   a web application other than the default zone, the query processor
>   does not map search-result URLs so that they are relative to the AAM
>   zone from which queries are performed. Instead, search-result URLS
>   will be relative to the non-default zone that was crawled. Because of
>   this, users might not readily be able to view or open search results.